# Applying SciPy optimization to a fitted sci-kit model

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, scipy, regression

Recently I have been facing a problem which I think that SciPy might be a good candidate to solve. However, I have not been able to properly apply it. Not sure if I am missing something or if what I am looking for is actually not possible at all.

This is a fictitious example which I made to makes things more clear and easier to visualize. My case is way more complicated.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

time_studied = [12, 10, 4, 7, 6, 11, 6]
hours_slept = [8, 7, 1, 3, 8, 6, 5]
grade = [10, 9, 2, 5, 7, 8, 8.5, 6]

X = np.array([time_studied, hours_slept]).T
y = np.array([grade]).T 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)    
model = SVR(kernel='poly', C=100, gamma='auto', degree=3, epsilon=.1, coef0=1)
model.fit(X,y)
```

Then, I am trying to apply an optimizer to that function to find what would be the optimal balance between sleep and study. As the tested regression method returns a function, then I guess that it would be possible to apply a SciPy minimize. But, when I try to apply it, with something like this

```
bnds = [(0,12), (0,8)]
x0 = [0,0]
residual_plant = minimize(model, x0, method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds,options = {'eps': np.radians(5.0)})
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: 'SVR' object is not callable
```

So, clearly it is possible to call an optimizer directly out of my model. Therefore, here it comes my question, how would it be possible to access the function fitted to my data and be able to find the optimal hours sleep+study time x grade (in this case it is obvious the expected result)

Am I missing something? Is it possible to do what I am aiming to?

Comment: I do not know what exactly minimize does. But just checking the documentation revealed that it is expecting a function to be optimized.Here instead of a function it is given an instance of the class SVR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```py
residual_plant = minimize(lambda x: model.predict(np.array([x])), x0, method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds,options = {'eps': np.radians(5.0)})
```

The first argument to SciPy's `minimize` is *not* just `model.predict` because SciPy tries to pass a 1D array to its objective function, but `model.predict` expects a 2D array.

(By the way, in the training setup for your fictitious model, `y` is the second column of `X` and the list `grades` is never used. I suspect that `y` is supposed to be `np.array([grades]).T`. Since that isn't your real model, that's probably not critical.)

Reference documentation for the `predict` method: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html?highlight=svr#sklearn.svm.SVR.predict

An example usage of the `predict` method can be found here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_regression.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-svm-regression-py

Comment: You are absolutely right on your correction. Just fixed it.

Comment: I believe that since the optimization goal is to MAXIMIZE grade, the objective function should multiply the predicted grades by -1 since it is being minimized